# using controllers as webServices: What is the equivalent to Page.Session?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I use controller as web service (not related to any view)

How can I imitate a `Page.Session` object ?

Comment: In controller you can access session via this.Session

Comment: By the if you use controller as service look for new webapi controller it's made right for you scenario

Comment: @DenisAgarev can you please add a link to this webapi ?

Comment: @DenisAgarev btw, is there any way to access this session dictionary from deeper bll code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access Session anywhere you like just with HttpContext.Session.

Check this out: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/02/16/asp-net-4-beta-released.aspx
It's it beta now but it will be released soon with MVC4.